# depreciation warning when I use sklearn imputer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

My code is quite simple, but it always pops out the warning like this:

```
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will
raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if
your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
(DeprecationWarning)
```

I don't know why it does not work even if I add `s.reshape(-1,1)` in the parentheses of `fit_transforms`.

The code is following:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,np.nan,5,np.nan,7,8])
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NAN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
x = pd.Series(imp.fit_transform(s).tolist()[0])
x
```

Comment: Please try to import all the libraries you're using. Here, presumbaly `pd` is pandas, for example, but it's not sure that everyone will guess that.

Comment: So are you getting a warning or an error? In case of a warning the code should still execute, so if it doesn't you likely have another issue